# Persist user security profile data at custom Claims

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

My application have to fetch data from external services with the usage of manually provided at profile/management by user `api key & api secret`.

I'd like to prevent a huge amount of retriving those necessary keys queries to database and persist it somewhere else (assuming that those keys won't be updated too frequently).

From my point of view it could be implemented with next options:

1. Use `MemoryCache` provider with `SlidingExpiration`;
2. Create a custom `Claim` and append it into existing `Identity` claims collection;

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if I've realized it right - claim's information is a part of data, which is used for serialization/deserialization at frontend<->backend interaction (I'm not quite confident about it, but suppose that it's used within cookies & tokens).

Actually these keys are also required for a several background processes (message queue consumers or scheduled jobs for example).

Would you mind letting me know a proper way for persiting such protected and frequently used fields in an optimized way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it's descriptive information about the user then adding it as claims would be appropriate. Just don't add too much data (e.g more than 4kb)

Comment: What about security perspective? Is there a way to decrypt this information at frontend?

Comment: When the claims are stored in the auth cookie the entire thing is encrypted so no, the client can not see the content.

Comment: Does the frontend need the api key/secret?

Comment: No, frontend does not need these api keys. It will be used at backend only.

Answer (score 3):

When you login using one of `SignInManager`'s sign-in methods, it sets a cookie on the browser with an access token in it. This cookie contains claims data. So in subsequent authorized requests, you can query the `User.Claims` field to access the required fields without making a trip to your datastore.

Now whether you choose to use claims or not totally depends on how often you need the API Key / Secret. Your claims are part of the access token. If sending the API key / Secret on every request is justified, claims is the ideal choice.

---

UPDATE:

Rather than decrypting the tokens at the frontend, it's better to send them to the frontend client along with the access token.

Incase you're not aware of [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) or [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) do check them out. It's probably got all that you need.

Comment: That's fine. A few more questions: does it mean that claims should be updated due to keys were updated (with the usage of sign-out flow)? is there a way to decrypt token and extract claims information at frontend?

Comment: @FSou1 Yes the api-secret claims will have to be kept updated, else they might get invalid. As for the decryption, while that's possible it's just better to send the claims data along with the access-token on login.

Comment: No no no, i'm not going to decrypt it on frontend but I'm really worry if it is secured (I mean nobody could steal and decrypt it).

Comment: @FSou1 TBH Identity's token generation is like a black box to me, so I'm not sure if they're encrypting it in the first place. Do check the libraries I linked above. You get to configure your key-pair and as long as your keys don't leave your auth-server you're all good.

Comment: I think i could persist this information at HttpContext.Session,- in this case data will be secured

Comment: @FSou1 yes, but your APIs will no longer be stateless. Like I said, claims is the ideal way if you don't want to query the database. You can easily encrypt the claims into the access-token on the server and your client wont be able to decrypt it (because the keys only exist on the server).